# How to process string input as 'None' as Nonetype

Tags: python, string, optparse, nonetype

In optparse module, I've an option which take a path value (say build).

Issue: I've a check if this option is None but its failing if one passes --build=None. 
Reason: The reason is default type for optparse is string, so it sets build='None' i.e as string type with value None.

One way is to use eval() method but it fails if someone provide a legit path
Or I could do
  if build or build.lower()=='none':

But then I've to do it for all other options too which by default take string inputs. Is there a better way?
Kindly advice.

Comment: I think you can map the `string` inputs to function using a `dictionary`, so as soon as it is not `NONE`, you can lookup in your `dictionary` to see what `function` to call. But since it is from command line argument, I think best to stick with `optparse`, or even `argparse`: http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused what the problem is...  Here is some code that I put together.

```
>>> import optparse
>>> import shlex
>>> parser = optparse.OptionParser()
>>> parser.add_option('--build',type=str,default=None)
<Option at 0x...: --build>
```

Provide `--build` option on "command line".

```
>>> options, args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split("--build=None"))
>>> print options
{'build': 'None'}
>>> options.build is None
False
>>> options, args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(""))
```

No `--build` option given on "command line"

```
>>> print options
{'build': None}
>>> options.build is None
True
```

As you can see, if `--build` is not provided on the commandline, it defaults to `None` (i.e. an object with type `NoneType`).  If build is provided and the string == "None", it returns a string "None".

If you insist on passing `--build=None` on the commandline, then it is a little ambiguous what you want optparse to do with that flag.  If it is a path for example, you could write a function to check if the path None exists: e.g.

```
import os.path
def path_exists(p):
    if(os.path.exists(p)): return p
    else: return None
...
parser.add_option('--build',type=path_exists,default=None)
```

Of course, path_exists can be as complicated as you want it to be for your application.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason, mgilson's answer is not useful, because you need the default to actually be something other than `None` or some other obvious non-value; for instance if you want the defautl to be something like `~/.foorc`, A solution I tend to use is to instead add a different "turn it off" option, usually prefixing it with a negation.

```
>>> import optparse
>>> import shlex
>>> parser = optparse.OptionParser()
>>> parser.add_option('--build', type=str, default="~/.foorc")
<Option at 0x...: --build>
>>> parser.add_option('--no-build', 
...                   dest="build",
...                   action="store_const",
...                   const=None)
<Option at 0x...: --no-build>
```

Sensible default, options are optional, after all

```
>>> options, args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(""))
>>> print options 
{'build': '~/.foorc'}
>>> options.build
'~/.foorc'
```

Can be disabled with `--no-build` option:

```
>>> options, args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split("--no-build"))
>>> print options
{'build': None}
>>> options.build is None
True
```

Of course, you can still override the default.

```
>>> options, args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split("--build=something"))
>>> print options
{'build': 'something'}
>>> options.build
'something'
```